# list all diffs between revisions on a file with svn

Tags: svn, diff

You can do `svn log myfile.java | less` and scroll up and down to see all the revisions made on a particular file

Is there any way to include the diff between revisions in that too?
I don't want to have to do `svn log | less`, find out the revisions, and manually do `svn diff -r<range>` on each pair ...

Answer (score 1):

Just include the [`--diff`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.diff) flag:

```
svn log myfile.java --diff | less
```

Comment: It was added in 1.7 (since it doesn't appear in the [1.6 red book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html)).  Update your svn client, 1.7 came out in 2011!